# While loop fail to read all line from file

Tags: bash, loops

So I got this bash script that perform a backup command from remote server, each server hostname is defined on file called `/tmp/quarantine.list`. The content is like this:

```sh
server1
server2
```

<sub>`server1` and `server2` is an ssh alias to my remote server, so if I need to access either of them I just run e.g. `ssh server1`.</sub>

I need to backup each server in `/tmp/quarantine.list`, so I loop each line using `while` loop. Here is my code.

```sh
    # Reading from /tmp/quarantine.list
while IFS= read -r list; do
  if [ "$list" == "server4" ]; then
    users="adminjoe"
  fi
  tempfile="${logdir}/rsync_$list.log"
  SECONDS=0
  set +x
  if rsync -ca --stats --info=progress2 --remove-source-files $list:/home/${users}/backup/20* $backup_location/$list >> $tempfile 2>&1; then
    ssh $list "find /home/${users}/backup/20* -type d -empty -delete"
  else
    echo "Error while running rsync"
    exit 1
  fi
  set -x
  elapsed_time=$SECONDS
  transferred_size=$(gawk 'BEGIN { FS=":" } {gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", $2)} /Total transferred file size/ { print $2 }' $tempfile | tr -cd "[:digit:]")
  echo "Backup of $list done at $(/bin/date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S') --> $(bytesToHumanReadable $transferred_size)" | tee -a "${HOME}/backup.log"
  echo "<b>$list --> $(bytesToHumanReadable $transferred_size)</b>" >> $konten
  echo "$transferred_size $list" >> $summaryfile_size
  echo "$elapsed_time $list" >> $summaryfile_time
done < "/tmp/quarantine.list"
rm "/tmp/quarantine.list"
```

The problem is my script only pick the first line of `/tmp/quarantine.list`, so for example if there was two remote in quarantine.

```sh
server2
server6
```

The script only process `server2`, while `server6` remains untouched. What's weird is, when I put `--dry-run` option to rsync, it will process all line in `/tmp/quarantine.list` without problem !

#### Without `--dry-run`

```sh
+ echo 'Backup of server2 done at 2021-10-28_16:55:26 --> 3.28 GB'
Backup of server2 done at 2021-10-28_16:55:26 --> 3.28 GB
++ bytesToHumanReadable 3280769140
++ S=("bytes" "kB" "MB" "GB" "TB" "PB" "EB" "YB" "ZB")
++ local i=3280769140 d= s=0 S
++ (( i > 1000 && s < 9-1 ))
++ printf -v d .%02d 14
++ i=3280769
++ s=1
++ (( i > 1000 && s < 9-1 ))
++ printf -v d .%02d 76
++ i=3280
++ s=2
++ (( i > 1000 && s < 9-1 ))
++ printf -v d .%02d 28
++ i=3
++ s=3
++ (( i > 1000 && s < 9-1 ))
++ echo '3.28 GB'
+ echo '<b>server2 --> 3.28 GB</b>'
+ echo '3280769140 server2'
+ echo '1883 server2'
+ IFS=
+ read -r list
+ rm /tmp/quarantine.list
```

#### With `--dry-run`

```sh
+ echo 'Backup of server2 done at 2021-10-28_16:07:14 --> 3.28 GB'
Backup of server2 done at 2021-10-28_16:07:14 --> 3.28 GB
++ bytesToHumanReadable 3280769140
++ S=("bytes" "kB" "MB" "GB" "TB" "PB" "EB" "YB" "ZB")
++ local i=3280769140 d= s=0 S
++ (( i > 1000 && s < 9-1 ))
++ printf -v d .%02d 14
++ i=3280769
++ s=1
++ (( i > 1000 && s < 9-1 ))
++ printf -v d .%02d 76
++ i=3280
++ s=2
++ (( i > 1000 && s < 9-1 ))
++ printf -v d .%02d 28
++ i=3
++ s=3
++ (( i > 1000 && s < 9-1 ))
++ echo '3.28 GB'
+ echo '<b>server2 --> 3.28 GB</b>'
+ echo '3280769140 server2'
+ echo '32 server2'
+ IFS=
+ read -r list
+ '[' server6 == server4 ']'
```

As you can see, the latter continues with `server6` as opposed of the former. I just wondering what I'd do wrong here?

Comment: Could it be that you are missing a line feed at the end of the last line?

Comment: @user1934428 No, I already check the file content. I can loop through them manually using `while` just fine.

Comment: What's the point of the `IFS=` in your case? I think this causes the whole file being read in the first iteration already. See [here]/https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS)

Comment: Add `-n` to your `ssh` command?

Comment: Yeah, Cyrus might be on to something, since `ssh` consumes `stdin` which is also being used by `read`, or use a different `fd` for the `while` + `read` loop.

Comment: Yes, that's probably this. Something in the loop is eating the second line. But if it happens only when `rsync` runs in real mode I would tend to suspect `rsync`. Use `RSYNC_PASSWORD` or `--password-file`, maybe?

Comment: This is faq 089 from wiki wooledge page.

Comment: @Cyrus Adding `-n` options fix the problem !

Comment: @Liso I do not understand: the `ssh` command shall be executed even when `rsync` runs in dry-run mode. How is it that it does not eat the second line in this case? Unless you also commented out the `ssh` command and forgot to mention that? If yes, please consider adding this information to your question, it will maybe help others with similar problems.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet You're right, I commented the ssh command on dry-run mode, I just realized this was the problem all along. Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen if the last line of the file does not end with a newline. Then `read` will actually read the line, but it will return a non-zero status (ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read). This non-zero status causes the `while` loop to end.

The idiomatic way to handle this is:

```sh
while IFS= read -r list || [[ -n $list ]]; do
```